# Can't copy the letters "ti" in a .pdf if in Calibri 12pt and made using Print>save to PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, copy-paste, print-to-pdf

When I save a document as a .pdf via Print>save to PDF, every single instance of the letters "ti" in 12pt Calibri in the .pdf will no longer be copied once the document reaches a particular size (don't know what that size is, but a text document with only a couple of words had no issues). It's basically as though the combination of "ti" simply does not exist as far as the computer is concerned.

What I'm mostly confused by is it's inconsistency.

- If done with a Google Docs document, the copy-pasted line will end where the first instance of "ti" should be.
- If done with LibreOffice Writer document, it pastes everything, but with every instance of "ti" replaced with a box, sometimes empty, sometimes with a ? inside.
- If done with a NotePad document, same as LibreOffice.
- If done in a WordPad document, the issue doesn't occur.
- Couldn't check Microsoft Word because the .pdf made using the Word document wouldn't allow me to highlight text, so I'm assuming it locked it in some way, or saved the text as an image.

Also, while the above examples of copying were done with Adobe Acrobat Reader, the symbol I get changes depending on where I copy the text from. So if I open the .pdf in Chrome or Edge, then copy the text, I get an upright oval with a horizontal line through the center.

Not sure where the actual issue is occurring. I thought it was a Windows problem at first,  .pdf made with a WordPad document didn't have the issue.

Not a huge issue, as most programs allow saving as a .pdf, which thus far hasn't caused issues, or I can just use a different font. It's only with print>save to PDF that this occurs, and I'm curious as to why and if anyone else has seen anything like this before.

[Link to the text I've been testing this with](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRlAiryvpbeYrOgk_tuIbSl6pouPaLJFUypEQnuALS53ZssHR1Xc4UH40gVdturnts40imWHCCyhjzj/pub).

Comment: Not at my computer so can't test. Sounds like it's using a ligature, a 'combo' single character rather than two individual glyphs. See if you can either force it to include the full font or switch off ligatures.

Comment: `ﬁ` <- U+FB01, the two characters f and i in the same symbol, a ligature. I tried to find "ti"  -but could not.

Comment: searching for "calibri ti ligature" may give you some clues

Comment: Hmmm… there's no unicode ligature for 'ti' so it's going to have to be something font-specific. If I force my font manager to show ligatures I see it does contain one. You're going to have to find a way to switch that off in your originating app if you need to copy/paste. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYKZq.png

Comment: Me too on Mac.  Exporting PDF from Pages.app with Calabir font, results in garbled text, when copying from PDF and pasting to another editor. https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/152075-trouble-with-loading-text-from-pdfs-ti-tt-ft/#comment-1166187

Answer (score 0):

From this [Affinity forum](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/152075-trouble-with-loading-text-from-pdfs-ti-tt-ft/&do=findComment&comment=1166203) I found an answer, which helped me with Pages.app on my MacBook.  I too had the issue with Calabri font, when copying from an exported PDF!

MikeTO wrote:

> You can avoid it by editing the document in Pages, selecting all of its text, and choosing **Format** > **Font** > **Ligature** > **Use None**.