# Text printed-to-pdf and copied-pasted back gets totally scrambled

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, fonts, print-to-pdf

Can anybody explain why my (admittedly absurd) following text is getting scrambled:

> "A sticky offbeat platform lift is often better than a cliffhanger fjord like Loefke.".

I have entered this text in a mail body with MS Outlook, then printed-to-pdf, opened pdf file, select all and copy and paste back to MS Outlook.

Now the same text reads:

> "A scky oeat plaorm li is oen beer than a clianger ord like Loee."

---

After some additional testing I believe it is only the Calibri font producing this. On the other hand Calibri is the standard font for outlook. Additionally I noticed that MS Word also shows this behavior. Excel, Powerpoint and Wordpad are fine even with Calibri.

Comment: Interesting ligature/kerning test, which I'll have to remember along with, "Quick brown fox..." In Mozilla's Thunderbird running on Windows OS and using T'Birds own "Save to PDF" utility, there was *no* issue going to PDF and back. BTW, have you tried different fonts? It's doubtful even Outlook would cause an issue with a monospaced one.

Comment: Why do you copy the email body in pdf back to Outlook email instead of using the original text in the Outlook email?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1743522/cant-copy-the-letters-ti-in-a-pdf-if-in-calibri-12pt-and-made-using-printsa